# Centralize popover display in xcode

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, popover

My popover border was only partially showing the view I wanted to display, so I used the line `self.buttonPopoverControllerH1.popoverContentSize = CGSizeMake(1000, 700);` to enlarge it.

While it did enlarge the popover, the view still isn't central, and so it is still only partially displayed. Does anyone know how to rectify this?

I can't use autolayout as I'm developing an app for ios 5. I can't link in an image as I don't have enough rep, but

[image]

is what I'm talking about. Only half the view is displayed.

Answer (score 1):

Set the rect when you present it..just modify to fit the frame you would like:

```
CGRect rect = CGRectMake(350,100,100,100);
[yourPopoverController presentPopoverFromRect:rect inView:self.view permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny animated:YES];
```

Comment: this works on the iOS simulator, but not on my ipad, any idea why?

Comment: The coordinates are all equal, which is fine as that's all I need. It works fine on the iOS simulator, however on my iPad the popovers shift and change place like they did before I added your snippet of code.

Comment: Yeah ive noticed that coordinates will be different when actually running on the device. Just run it a few times and tweak it

Answer (score 0):

Do you want the popover view to take up most of the screen? If so, you should consider using a Modal View, instead of a popover view. Popover views shouldn't really cover the entire screen.

Comment: The popover view is what I want. After using tdevoy's fix, it works on the ios simulator, but not on my ipad. Any idea why?